# vim8: update PYTHONPATH in vimrc only

Tags: python, vim, neovim

Because of some restrictions on my work server, I can't install python packages system wide. I'm using pyenv to have some additional features (like neovim's python package) and I'm currently exporting `PYTHONPATH=path/to/my/env/lib/site-packages` in my bashrc to make vim happy.

However, I'd like to avoid updating my `PYTHONPATH` globally, and (if that's possible) only update it in my .vimrc, so that only vim/vim's plugin are using the additional packages.

Is that possible ? How can I update vim's python configuration ?

So far I tried to use `g:python3_host_prog` and set it to `path/to/my/env/bin/python` but vim is still using the system one.
As I am using a source build vim, should I set some option at compile time to point to the right python ?

Comment: I think you need `--with-python-config-dir`. Something like `./configure --with-features=huge --enable-pythoninterp --prefix=path/to/my/env --with-python-config-dir=path/to/my/env/lib/python2.7/config`. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bvim%5D+compile

Comment: Is this something I can find in my pyenv environment ?

Comment: Should be there. Could have a different name. For example in my Debian the directory is `/usr/lib/python2.7/config-i386-linux-gnu/`.

Comment: Still trying to find mine.. I found some for python2 but nothing for python3. If you have anything inside your python3 config, I'd love to have a listing to try to find the same on my station

Comment: For Python 3.7 I have `/home/phd/.local/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-i386-linux-gnu`. The same for other Pythons.

Comment: One solution that I personally don't like, but may suit you just fine, would be to alias vim.  Something like `alias vim="PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/my/env/lib/site-packages vim"`.  Edit: Just saw that you're building your own vim so clearly configuring it to point to the right python is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I do this (in Neovim):

```
let g:python_host_prog = expand($XDG_DATA_HOME).'/virtualenvs/nvimp2-sk9zInl9/bin/python'
let g:python3_host_prog = expand($XDG_DATA_HOME).'/virtualenvs/nvimp3-VnFM7OAS/bin/python'
```

having created the respective virtualenvs (using pipenv if memory serves) and `XDG_DATA_HOME` gets set to `~/.local/share` in `.profile`. So I can certify that setting these values definitely works (and the output of `:checkhealth` is correct). However, I don't build Vim from source.

I imagine you've already seen it, but just in case: [Setting up Python for Neovim](https://github.com/deoplete-plugins/deoplete-jedi/wiki/Setting-up-Python-for-Neovim).